# Downloading html source code is slow

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm using jsoup in my android app but the problem is, the html source takes too much time to download. Here is my code:

```
    long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/";
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        Connection c = Jsoup.connect(url);
        doc = c.get();
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - t);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Executing this code takes 1.265 seconds which feels really weird because i can download the whole website (with images and all that good stuff) using web browser in less than a 0.5 seconds on the same device. Did I do something wrong? Or maybe there is a faster way for getting html source of website? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you clear all the caches from the browser before testing?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying this code on? Your device? If you are using the LTE/3G network it wouldn't be too much off.

The other reason that I could think is that your wireless router is not situated in the best place from your device in case you are using Wifi.

From that code I don't see anything that could cause more delay. 1.2 secs may not be that bad if you dont have the host DNS entry cached and the server is far away from you.

Also, try setting the Agent to the same as your browser when comparing times. It may happen that the server gives different priorities based on the user agent. In this case you are using the default Java user agent.